# Multiple Create Criteria re-use code grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a create criteria using multiple params with pagination.
The issue that I´m having that if is possible to re-use the code inside the and for others create-criteria totally differents, witouth having to duplicate the code.
I reffer that if I have the cases createcriteria and want to do the same "filters" on the cases2 not have to duplicate the code, unify both createCriteria is not an option
Per example, the problem that I´m facing is that one needs to be with pagination, and other don´t need to be, and both needs to access distinct fields, so the unique option is to create two identical create criteria if I´m not missing something.
That is a example, that cases is at least 90% indetically to cases2, and what would be a good mode to reuse the code?

```
 def cases = PpCase.createCriteria().list{ 
            and{
                if(limit){
                    maxResults(limit)
                }
                firstResult(offset)
                order("mostRecentPaymentDate", "desc")
                order("totalAmount", "desc")
                if(params.admin_id){
                    eq("adminId",params.admin_id)
                }
                if(params.status){
                    eq("status",params.status.toUpperCase() as PpCase.Status)
                }
                if(params.date_from){
                    ge('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_from))
                }
                if(params.date_to){
                    le('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_to))
                }
                if(params.date_closed_from){
                    ge('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_from))
                }
                if(params.date_closed_to){
                    le('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_to))
                }
        }
}

def cases2 = PpCase.createCriteria().list{ 
            and{
                firstResult(offset)
                order("mostRecentPaymentDate", "desc")
                order("totalAmount", "desc")
                if(params.admin_id){
                    eq("adminId",params.admin_id)
                }
                if(params.status){
                    eq("status",params.status.toUpperCase() as PpCase.Status)
                }
                if(params.date_from){
                    ge('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_from))
                }
                if(params.date_to){
                    le('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_to))
                }
                if(params.date_closed_from){
                    ge('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_from))
                }
                if(params.date_closed_to){
                    le('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_to))
                }
        }
}
```

More real example:
In cases I need some fields, but with a limit , and in cases2 I need distinct fields, and witouth a limit,I´m duplicating the 90% of the code.

```
     def cases = PpCase.createCriteria().list{ 
                projections {
                    sum("field1")
                    countDistinct("id")
                }
              and{
               if(limit){
                    maxResults(limit)
                }
           //HERE SHOULD BE THE CODE THAT I NEED TO REUTILIZE
 }
 def cases2 = PpCase.createCriteria().list{ 
                projections {
                    sum("field2")
                    countDistinct("id")
                }
              and{

           //HERE SHOULD BE THE CODE THAT I NEED TO REUTILIZE
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "unify both createCriteria is not an option", especially considering in the code above you are executing the exact same query twice and ending up with two lists containing the same rows.

One way to reuse your criteria is to just define the criteria as a seperate closure, and pass that to createCriteria.

```
Closure fetchPayments = { 
        and{
            if(limit){
                maxResults(limit)
            }
            firstResult(offset)
            order("mostRecentPaymentDate", "desc")
            order("totalAmount", "desc")
            if(params.admin_id){
                eq("adminId",params.admin_id)
            }
            if(params.status){
                eq("status",params.status.toUpperCase() as PpCase.Status)
            }
            if(params.date_from){
                ge('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_from))
            }
            if(params.date_to){
                le('dateCreated', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_to))
            }
            if(params.date_closed_from){
                ge('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_from))
            }
            if(params.date_closed_to){
                le('closedDate', Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd",params.date_closed_to))
            }
    }
}

def cases  = PpCase.createCriteria().list(fetchPayments)
def cases2 = PpCase.createCriteria().list(fetchPayments)
```

Comment: Yes, the example is the same createCriteria to simplify the things, but the code is a little different, do different projections and the parts that need to reuse is the and{ } conditions of the createCriteria i will upload a example

Comment: Added example more real

Comment: In that case, it's just a small change to the original answer; keeping your separately defined closure 'fetchPayments', just call that closure as part of your criteria building where you need two scenarios.
`
    def cases = PpCase.createCriteria().list {
        delegate.with fetchPayments
        /* cases 1 specific criteria here */
    }

    def cases2 = PpCase.createCriteria().list {
        delegate.with fetchPayments
        /* cases 2 specific criteria here */
    }
`

Comment: Yes, I´m testing it in this moment, I think that should work.

Comment: I tested  def cases = PpCase.createCriteria().list(fetchPayments) with the fetchpayment that you reffered and received groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: limit for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
Passing params to the clouse ,I receive
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: webserver.PpCaseService.and() is applicable for argument types: (webserver.PpCaseService$_closure1_closure12)
And the second option
And the   PpCase.createCriteria().list { delegate.with  {fetchPayments }  }  don´t throw error,but didn´t work at all

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off. The line should read `delegate.with fetchPayments` (or `delegate.with(fetchPayments)`), not `delegate.with { fetchPayments }`

Comment: I edited it, but still give me some issues
def cases = PpCase.createCriteria().list{delegate.with clos(params)} 
Closure clos = { params ->
                        eq("adminId",'oneperson')
                     } 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: webserver.PpCaseService.eq() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Well solved putting the closure on the same method that the function, seems to be some issues when calling with parameters, or something like that, but whatever it get solved with that workaround ,maybe if you know you can clarify what you would do to pass the parameters, to provide the solution more generally.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use ["where" queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries), which use `DetachedCriteria` under the hood, or [`DetachedCriteria` directly](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria). where queries don't run until you call `list`/`get`/`count`/`exists`/`deleteAll`/`updateAll`, so they're great candidates for composing queries in parts. Named queries can similarly be composed, but they need to be complete, runnable queries, but a partial where query is fine as long as you add the missing parts via composition before running them. They're also more flexible since you can use them to delete and update.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using named query :
have look to documentation .[namedQueries](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)

Comment: I will check it, I will get the answer open a bit more to see if iI get another response!